# define class and pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I have this main:
(part of the code).

```
int main ()
{
Person* pPerson;
ifstream file ("data.dat", ios::binary);
pPerson = personFactory::getPersonFromFile(file);
...
}
```

Can I define the calls that...?
(part of the class).

```
class personFactory{
public:
...
Person* getPersonFromFile (ifstream& inFile);
...
};
```

Comment: "Can I define the calls that...?" - [WAT?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question, but yes, something like that works just fine. You can have a "Helper" class which generates a third class, as you described. Note that you have to initiate personFactory like that, otherwise make it a static function.

Comment: What are the reasons that prevent you from creating `Person::Person(ifstream&)` constructor, actually? Also, use `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if your call looks like

```
personFactory::getPersonFromFile(file)
```

you need to have it static

```
 static Person* getPersonFromFile (ifstream& inFile);
```

Comment: Also don't forget, as you will return a pointer on person you have to create it with "new". Otherwise the Object will run out of scope and the Pointer points to an destroyed object in memory

Comment: and if I will using:
static Person* getPersonFromFile (ifstream& inFile)const;
it will not wirking right? (because Person is not const?).